# Gem.latest_load_paths was removed in Ruby 2 and breaks Rails tmbundle. How do I help fix it?

Tags: ruby

I use TextMate's [RoR bundle](https://github.com/drnic/ruby-on-rails-tmbundle), which uses `Gem.latest_load_paths`, which was removed in Ruby 2. This breaks Jump to Method Definition, among other things, and I'd like to help fix it. I already fixed the problem for myself by forcing TextMate to use Ruby 1.9.3, but I'd like to fix it at the source by making a pull request to the bundle. Only I'm not sure if I should roll my own definition of `latest_load_paths`, which I [saw spork do](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/commit/50c670dd46720efb0f6c477166f377f00b707f07), or figure out exactly why `latest_load_paths` was removed and make a fix that doesn't 'fight' the Ruby team's intentions.

I set out to find why `latest_load_paths` was abandoned, but the [commit messages](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/d22130922e7842226d38d59680e4bbb48a28a5f0) don't seem to tell me much. So I'm stumped.

I have several questions:

1. What's the best practice for handling this particular deprecated method?
2. What's the best practice for dealing with methods that are 'deprecated without replacement' in general?
3. It seems to me the Ruby project's commit messages are not particularly helpful for finding out why methods are deprecated, or what the authors recommend you use instead. How would one go about finding out those things?

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change on line 75 in `jump_to_method_definition.rb`

Replace

`Gem.latest_load_paths.each do |directory|`

with

`Gem.path.each do |directory|`

and that should fix it.

Comment: `Gem.path` didn't do it, but `Gem.paths.path` did, so thanks for the pointer! Any comments on my second and third questions?

Comment: Should be the same "[6] pry(main)> Gem.path
=> ["/Users/xxxx/.gem/ruby/2.3.0", "/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0"]
[7] pry(main)> Gem.paths.path
=> ["/Users/xxxx/.gem/ruby/2.3.0", "/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0"]"

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad, I did `Gem.paths` instead of `Gem.path`!